# Store audio from QAudioInput and pass it to SciPy FFT

Tags: python, audio, scipy, pyqt, pyqt5

how can I get audio input in real time from QAudioInput, store it in a NumPy array and pass it to SciPy FFT? What I have tried:

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDeviceInfo, QAudioFormat, QAudioInput
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        info = QAudioDeviceInfo()
        input_device = info.defaultInputDevice()
        if input_device.isNull():
            # If no avaiable device is found, we display a error
            print("There is no audio input device available.")
            exit(-1)

        audio_format = QAudioFormat()
        audio_format.setSampleRate(44100)
        audio_format.setSampleSize(8)
        audio_format.setChannelCount(1)
        audio_format.setCodec("audio/pcm")
        audio_format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.UnSignedInt)

        if sys.byteorder == "little":
            audio_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
        else:
            audio_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.BigEndian)
        self.audioInput = QAudioInput(input_device, audio_format, self)
        self.ioDevice = self.audioInput.start()
        self.ioDevice.readyRead.connect(self.read_audio)

    def read_audio(self):
        data: QByteArray = self.ioDevice.readAll()
        print(data.toUInt()) # Prints (0, False) which means error converting data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired by the official example [Audio Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-audio-example.html) I have created a QIODevice that allows obtaining the data. The following example takes the last N samples every T seconds by calculating its fft and displaying it using matplotlib.

```py
import sys
import collections
from functools import cached_property


from PyQt5.QtCore import QIODevice, QObject, pyqtSignal, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDeviceInfo, QAudioFormat, QAudioInput
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from scipy.fft import fft, fftfreq
import numpy as np

FS = 44100
SAMPLE_COUNT = 2 * 1000


class AudioDevice(QIODevice):
    data_changed = pyqtSignal(list, name="dataChanged")

    def __init__(self, interval=1000, parent: QObject = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.m_buffer = collections.deque(
            [0 for _ in range(SAMPLE_COUNT)], maxlen=SAMPLE_COUNT
        )
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.send_data)
        self.timer.setInterval(interval)
        self.timer.start()

    @cached_property
    def timer(self):
        return QTimer()

    def send_data(self):
        self.data_changed.emit(list(self.m_buffer))

    def readData(self, data, max_size):
        return -1

    def writeData(self, data):
        max_size = len(data)
        resolution = 4

        start = 0
        available_samples = int(max_size) // resolution

        if available_samples < self.m_buffer.maxlen:
            start = self.m_buffer.maxlen - available_samples
        pos = 0
        for _ in range(start, self.m_buffer.maxlen):
            y = (1.0 * (data[pos] - 128)) / 128.0
            self.m_buffer.append(y)
            pos += resolution

        return (self.m_buffer.maxlen - start) * resolution


class PlotWidget(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        self.ax = self.canvas.figure.subplots()
        self._line = None

    def update_data(self, data):
        T = 1 / FS
        N = SAMPLE_COUNT
        yf = fft(data)
        xf = fftfreq(N, T)[: N // 2]

        x = xf
        y = 2.0 / N * np.abs(yf[0 : N // 2])

        if self._line is None:
            (self._line,) = self.ax.plot(x, y)
        else:
            self._line.set_data(x, y)
        self.canvas.draw()


def main(args):
    app = QApplication(args)

    plot_widget = PlotWidget()
    plot_widget.resize(640, 480)
    plot_widget.show()

    info = QAudioDeviceInfo()
    input_device = info.defaultInputDevice()
    if input_device.isNull():
        print("There is no audio input device available.")
        exit(-1)

    audio_format = QAudioFormat()
    audio_format.setSampleRate(FS)
    audio_format.setSampleSize(8)
    audio_format.setChannelCount(1)
    audio_format.setCodec("audio/pcm")
    audio_format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.UnSignedInt)

    if sys.byteorder == "little":
        audio_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
    else:
        audio_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.BigEndian)

    audio_input = QAudioInput(input_device, audio_format, None)

    audio_device = AudioDevice(interval=100)
    audio_device.data_changed.connect(plot_widget.update_data)
    audio_device.open(QIODevice.WriteOnly)
    audio_input.start(audio_device)

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! How can I make bigger the Y axis of the plot? Otherwise the result seems a bit bad. For example here is a way of doing this using PyAudio and the result is extremely good https://github.com/swharden/Python-GUI-examples/tree/master/2016-07-37_qt_audio_monitor

Comment: @PepeElMago33 Note: The image of the link that you indicate does not normalize the data, instead I normalize it from -1 to + 1. Typically the signals are analyzed in db, not in absolute values, in my case it would be necessary to apply the logarithm.

Comment: @PepeElMago33 Besides applying a hamming filter, my code shows a trivial example that you can refine (I don't want to take away that privilege :-)).

Comment: Why do you override `readData` and just return an error and instead use `writeData` method?

Answer (score 1):

`data.toUInt()` converts whole byte array to one uint value - not what you want. To get sample values you can use either `numpy.frombuffer` or `struct.unpack`.

```
import numpy

def read_audio(self):
    data = self.ioDevice.readAll()
    values = numpy.frombuffer(data.data(), dtype=numpy.uint8)
```

or

```
import struct

def read_audio(self):
    data = self.ioDevice.readAll()
    fmt = "@{}B".format(data.size())
    values = struct.unpack(fmt, data.data())
```

Comment: Now all the values are either 127 or 128 or 129, do you know why?

Comment: I guess that 127 is "virtual zero" value and sound wave spans between 0 and 255 as f(t) = sin(freq * 2 * pi) * amp + 127. Make some noise and youll get other values.

Comment: Then I try to normalize it by subtracting 128 and then divide it by 128 but some values are bigger than 1. In fact the values are between 0 and 2, but are completely random noise, not real audio from mic

Comment: @PepeElMago33 see my other answer

Answer (score 1):

I added widget that shows waveform to demonstrate that samples actually reflect signal from microphone - not random numbers.

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QAudioDeviceInfo, QAudioFormat, QAudioInput
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPolygonF
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPointF
import sys
import numpy

class WaveWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._values = None

    def setValues(self, values):
        self._values = values
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self._values is None:
            return
        painter = QPainter(self)
        ys = self._values / 255 * self.height()
        xs = numpy.linspace(0, self.width(), num = len(ys))
        points = QPolygonF([QPointF(x,y) for x,y in zip(xs,ys)])
        painter.drawPolyline(points)

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        info = QAudioDeviceInfo()
        input_device = info.defaultInputDevice()
        if input_device.isNull():
            # If no avaiable device is found, we display a error
            print("There is no audio input device available.")
            exit(-1)

        audio_format = QAudioFormat()
        audio_format.setSampleRate(44100)
        audio_format.setSampleSize(8)
        audio_format.setChannelCount(1)
        audio_format.setCodec("audio/pcm")
        audio_format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat.UnSignedInt)

        if sys.byteorder == "little":
            audio_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.LittleEndian)
        else:
            audio_format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat.BigEndian)
        self.audioInput = QAudioInput(input_device, audio_format, self)
        self.ioDevice = self.audioInput.start()
        self.ioDevice.readyRead.connect(self.read_audio)
        widget = WaveWidget()
        self._widget = widget
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

    def read_audio(self):
        data = self.ioDevice.readAll()
        values = numpy.frombuffer(data.data(), dtype=numpy.uint8)
        self._widget.setValues(values)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```